# I'm making a checklist and I would like this data to be updated/inserted using an iframe or any alternative method Ask Question

Tags: visualforce, html, slds, iframe

[image]

So This here is my check list and above it is where my Iframe should display. From my understanding it is not being displayed because of "Clickjacking" protection. Is there any way I can display my page without disabling the Clickjack protection?

Any alternative methods to using Iframes?

Its strange because I can open external sites.

Also quick note, the button at the top works and goes directly to the related record. I would just prefer it in an Iframe

Here is the code:-

```
<!--Apprentice Section -->

        <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-size_1-of-1 slds-box" Style="Width:100%;">
        <div class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-p-around_small slds-size_1-of-1 slds-text-color_default"><b>Apprentice Section </b><div class="slds-button slds-button_neutral">
            <apex:outputLink target="_Blank" value="{!Paperwork__c.Apprentice_Link__c}" id="ApprenticeLink" ><div class="slds-text-body_small"> <b>Update Apprentice Section </b></div></apex:outputLink>
        </div></div>
        <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-size_1-of-1 slds-box" Style="Width:100%;">
        <iframe height="300px" id="theIframe" name="theIframe" src="http://www.salesforce.com" width="100%"></iframe>
        </div>

        <!--Head Row -->

              <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_shade slds-text-heading_medium" Style = "">
                    <span><b>DATA</b></span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_shade slds-text-heading_medium" Style = "">
                    <span><b>CHECK</b></span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-text-heading_medium" Style = "">
                    <span><b>DATA</b></span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-text-heading_medium" Style = "">
                    <span><b>CHECK</b></span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_shade slds-text-heading_medium" Style = "">
                    <span><b>DATA</b></span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_shade slds-text-heading_medium" Style = "">
                    <span><b>CHECK</b></span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-text-heading_medium" Style = "">
                    <span><b>DATA</b></span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-text-heading_medium" Style = "">
                    <span><b>CHECK</b></span>
              </div>

         <!--/Head Row -->

          <!--Row 1-->

          <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-size_1-of-1">
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-text-heading_small slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px">
                    <span><b>Apprentice Name</b></span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_shade " Style = "Height:100px">
                    <span><apex:outputField Value="{! Paperwork__c.Ck_Apprentice_Name__c}"/></span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-text-heading_small" Style = "Height:100px">
                    <span><b>Date of Birth</b></span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center" Style = "Height:100px">
                    <span><apex:outputField Value="{! Paperwork__c.Ck_Date_Of_Birth__c}"/></span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-text-heading_small slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px">
                    <span><b>Assessor</b></span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px">
                    <span><apex:outputField Value="{! Paperwork__c.Ck_Assessor__c}"/></span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-text-heading_small" Style = "Height:100px">
                    <span><b>Competence APL</b></span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center" Style = "Height:100px">
                    <span><apex:outputField Value="{! Paperwork__c.Ck_Competence_Aim_to_Deliver__c}"/></span>
              </div>
              </div>

              <!--/Row 1-->
```

Thanks for any and all help

Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [apex:include](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_include.htm) to inject one page in to another page, or consider using an [apex:component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_component.htm) instead; they are meant to be reusable containers for your your logic.